# How do I issue a quickbooks cash refund for returned items using qbxml

Tags: quickbooks-online, qbxml

I have been beating my head against this wall for days.

Tried credit memos... but they won't issue refund.

Tried credit memo plus check (memo cash) but it must be written against a bank account.

Sales Receipt won't allow negative totals

Invoices won't allow negative totals

There seems to be a Refund Receipt in Quickbooks but cannot find it in qbxml....

Answer (score 0):

QuickBooks *Online* has a `Refund Receipt` object:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/refundreceipt

QuickBooks *for Windows/Desktop* has checks and expenses you can do this with:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop/checkadd
- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop/billadd

Comment: I am interfacing with Desktop....Checks are required to be written agains "Bank Accounts".  In my case because I am refunding Cash at the point of sale, I want to refund from my undeposited funds account...which is not a Bank.

Comment: The only viable hack I have found is to use ARRefundCreditCard and create a fake Credit card payment method called "Cash Refund".  With that I can reference the credit memo I create for the return and issue a "cash" refund from undeposited funds.  Only issue is the refund is labeled a "Credit Card Refund" in Quickbooks, but alas the refund via is labeled "Cash Refund".....far from perfect but it seems to be my only viable option.